# Can I bevel this shape cleanly?

Tags: modeling, mesh, topology, bevel

I'm modelling a curved shape, and I'd like to bevel the edges. When I try to do that, the faces pucker. I've tried smooth shading the model, but it prevents any bevels from showing. Do I need to fix the topology?[image: Model]

[image: Beveled]

[image: Flat Shaded]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go into Edit Mode, select your whole mesh, and go to *Face > Tris to Quads*. This merges adjacent triangular faces into quads, which the Bevel modifier (and pretty much anything else) works best with.

Try beveling again and it should work better. If you want to convert back to tris again after beveling, just go to *Face > Triangulate Faces*.

Comment: Thanks, it worked! :-) I had to do some manual cleanup before bevelling. Mostly merging faces, subdividing with the knife tool, sliding edges and dissolving vertices where needed.